# Scroll to specific div after loading page when clicking an item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, joomla2.5, virtuemart

What i need is to click on a dropdown selection that redirect me to another page. When the page is loaded it has to scroll to a specific div.

The scenario is: a customer click into a drop down box and he is being redirected in a page scrolled down to the product section.

I manage to get this done only if the page doesn't reload or load every time e.g in middle of the page. (with some modifications)

My sample code at this momement is:

```
    <div class="product-field product-field-type-A"> <span class="product-fields-title-wrapper"><span class="product-fields-title"><strong>Choose</strong></span>
</span> <span class="product-field-display"><select id="field0custom_value" name="field[0][custom_value]" size="4" class="inputbox">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Apples</option>
    <option value="">Oranges</option>
</select>
</span>
    <span class="product-field-desc"></span>

    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="header">Header</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#field0custom_value").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#header").offset().top},
        'slow');
});
```

PS. all the above will is being integrated in Virtuemart + Joomla 2.5
(at the moment clicking the select box is broken and I cant' figure it out at the moment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to jump to a specific anchor on page B after clicking a (selectbox) item in page A?

Actually this can be done with less Javascript than you thought and actually without any Javascript too (but not without adding backend logic or using links instead of `select` boxes).

**Page A**

```
$(function(){
    $("body").delegate("#target", "change", function(e){
        // >>> this is the interesting line 
        location.href = "destination.html#" + $(target).val();
    });
});

</script>

<select id="target">
    <option value="target1">Target 1</option>
    <option value="target2">Target 2</option>
    <option value="target3">Target 3</option>
</select>
```

*Changes the location appending a "hash"*

**Page B**

```
<br><!-- 20 of them; only to blow up the page height (or real content) -->
<br>
<div id="target1">Target 1</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="target2">Target 2</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="target3">Target 3</div>
<br>
<br>
```

*The `id` attribute refers to the hash value (anchor), alternatively add `<a name="target1" />`*

You may do this without any Javascript in Page A too when using links:

```
 <a href="destination.html#target1">Target A</a>
```

Comment: This should do the trick, indeed it was more simple that I thought :)!

Comment: @user3127632 I'd be happy to receive an upvote from you if you think my answer is good and useful. :)